# How to reconcile mismatch in the signatures of stateFn and errorf in Rob Pike's lexical scanning talk?

Tags: go, lexer, lexical-analysis

This question pertains to the (remarkable!) lecture by Rob Pike (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE&t=555s)

How can the `errorf` method of type `lexer` be considered of type `stateFn`? It has a different signature than other `stateFn`s. How is `lexer`'s `run()` method able to run the line `state = state(l)` after `errorf` is returned in the previous iteration? `nil` is returned only after the `errorf` is actually run. And to run `errorf`, it needs to be invoked with `(format, args...)`. How can it accept a `(*lexer)` when invoked as `state(l)` in the `run()` method?﻿

Comment: errorf is never returned, it is invoked and all it does is emit the error and then return nil. run checks if the returned stateFn is not nil and continues if that's true, else the loop is terminated. (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/24a088d20ad52c527f61b34217da72589e366833/src/text/template/parse/lex.go)

Comment: Of course! It is returning what errorf *returns*, which is nil. It's so obvious now. This ends up being a silly question. Thanks for your reply!